# google analytics does't send screen view in android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have implemented google analytics in my android app for a long time and it works pretty well, until now I'm facing with a problem that it not **sends screen view.**

I have added this line under dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
```

My class AnalyticsManager have some functionalities:

```
    public static synchronized void initializeAnalyticsTracker(Context context) {
            sAppContext = context;

                mTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-Y");
            }

            GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(sAppContext).setLocalDispatchPeriod(3);
        }
```

And this is the function to send screen view:

```
    public static void sendScreenView(String screenName) {
            if (mTracker != null && sAppContext != null) {
                mTracker.setScreenName(screenName);
                mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
                //mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
                GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(sAppContext).dispatchLocalHits();

                LOGD(TAG, "Screen View recorded: " + screenName);

            } else {
                LOGD(TAG, "Screen View NOT recorded (analytics disabled or not ready).");
            }
        }
```

Does anyone can help me how does it can't send screen view?

Answer (score 0):

Your using old SDK tools and goolge play services.Please update your Android SDK tools and Google play services,because latest google play service will provide the inbuilt in google analytic service no need to add libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar file to your project.Then you will simple use these method and import statemnets.
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

private Tracker  tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-XXXXXX-X");
            tracker.setScreenName(screenName);

Comment: Hi Borra, I know I'm using the old one, so how can I upgrade to the new one, can you help me or give me an example? Currently I'm using dependencies, not add libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar to project

Comment: Hi It's simple...just update your eclipse sdk tools and google play services...then remove the  libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar from the lib folder.follow this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#manifest.You need to create Application class in your main package.

Comment: I'm not using libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar, currently I'm using dependencies to download the play services, please read my comment again.